# Why is eval is not a function for other users

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a clickable button in my sheet for my users on mobile.

I took help from
https://medium.com/macadamscripts/create-button-in-google-sheets-mobile-2979579025ef

I made a drop down in Column A with validation "Call_Customer" or "Call_Alt_No". Users are allowed to edit only Column A.

and made the below functions

```
//
//
function on_Edit(e) {
  //if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
      //e.range.setValue("Calling");
    }
  //}
}
//
//
function Call_Customer(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var cr=sht.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cu=sht.getRange("K"+cr).getValue();
  var ag=sht.getRange("J"+cr).getValue();
  const url = 'https://api.servetel.in/v1/click_to_call'
  const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'xxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  payload: JSON.stringify({agent_number: ag, destination_number: cu})
  }
  try {
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
    Logger.log(JSON.parse(res));
    //ss.toast(JSON.parse(res));
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log('error' + e);
    //ss.toast('error' + e);
  }
}
//
//
function Call_Alt_No(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var cr=sht.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cu=sht.getRange("I"+cr).getValue();
  var ag=sht.getRange("J"+cr).getValue();
  const url = 'https://api.servetel.in/v1/click_to_call'
  const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'xxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  payload: JSON.stringify({agent_number: ag, destination_number: cu})
  }
  try {
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
    //console.log(JSON.parse(res))
    //Browser.msgBox("Call Started");
  }
  catch (e) {
    //console.error('error' + e);
    //Browser.msgBox("Call failed");
  }
}
```

I made an installable trigger as simple trigger was not able to call external service.

The function Call_Customer runs well on my mobile - I am the owner. But it gives error for other editors of the sheet on their mobile (the error is available in the trigger log)

TypeError: eval(...) is not a function
at on_Edit(Code:33:20)

Is there any restriction for editors from using eval? Do they have to give any permission?

Comment: Do the other users use your code or make a copy of it? Mind that eval is not supported in the old runtime (Rhino) - so it won't work for users who don't have v8 enabled.